# @react-pdf/renderer only displays pdf on first render

Tags: node.js, electron, react-pdf, electron-react-boilerplate

Im currently using react-pdf/renderer and the [Electron-React-Boilerplate](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate).  If I restart my app, the pdf is generated and visible. If I close the page and reopen it, the location where the pdf is is blank.

[image]

```
const PdfOrcamentoItem = ({ item }: PropsItem) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.section}>
      <Text>{item.Descricao}</Text>
      {item.FrontImage ? <Image src={item.FrontImage} /> : null}
    </View>
  );
};
export const OrcamentoTest = ({ items }: Props) => {
  return (
    <Document key={items.length}>
      <Page size="A4" style={styles.page}>
        {items.map((item) => (
          <PdfOrcamentoItem item={item} key={item.Ordem} />
        ))}
      </Page>
    </Document>
  );
};
//-------------------------

export function MyPdf({ items }: Props) {
  return (
    <PDFViewer width="100%" height="100%">
      <OrcamentoTest items={items} />
    </PDFViewer>
  );
}
//--------------------------

// how I call the component
<BasicModal
        title="PDF"
        onClose={() => {
          setPdfModalOpen(false);
        }}
        open={pdfModalOpen}
        fullScreen
      >
        {pdfModalOpen ? (
          <MyPdf items={itemsRef.current} />
        ) : null}
      </BasicModal>
```

Even if I display just a download link for the pdf file instead of trying to display it, it only work on the first render of the component.  After that the `instance.url` becomes null.

```
function MyPdf({ items }: Props) {
  const test = <OrcamentoTest items={items} />;
  const [instance, updateInstance] = usePDF({ document: test });

  if (instance.loading) return <div>Loading ...</div>;

  if (instance.error) return <div>Something went wrong</div>;

  return instance.url ? (
    <a href={instance.url} download="test.pdf">
      Download
    </a>
  ) : (
    <div>Something went wrong</div>
  );
}


// versions
// "react": "^17.0.1",
// "@react-pdf/renderer": "^2.0.17",
```

I am starting to think that it might be a webpack configuration, but really have no idea.  I have followed the react-pdf instructions and don't see where the problem could be.  If someone has any idea that could lead me in the right direction, that would be great.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to avoid the problem by downgrading my `@react-pdf/renderer` version to `2.0.16`. It was a version bug.

[Github Bug Report](https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf/issues/1432)